# Add rel attribute of select dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a form where I'd like to show the user a running total of the options they've selected. However, I need to use the value of the field in the PHP that processes the form (it sends an e-mail with what options the user selected from multiple dropdown menus).

Therefore, I'd like to put the numeric total in the 'rel' attribute and sum that instead. Here's an example:

```
<option value="1x VIP Ticket" id="one" rel="160">1x VIP Ticket</option>
```

I have used the following jquery code before to do this with checkboxes, is it possible to make it work with select menus? I don't think there is, looking at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/ ...so perhaps a way to do this with vanilla JS?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
             sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });

});`
```

Here's the revised code to the use the data attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("#game1, #game2 option:selected").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).data("total"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("#game1, #game2 option:selected").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });

});

</script>

Tickets for Game 1
<select name="game1" id="game1">
<option value="1x VIP Ticket" id="1vip" data-total="160">1x VIP Ticket</option>
<option value="1x Regular Ticket" id="1regular" data-total="100">1x Regular Ticket</option>
</select>

Tickets for Game 2
<select name="game2" id="game2">
<option value="1x VIP Ticket" id="2vip" data-total="160">1x VIP Ticket</option>
<option value="1x Regular Ticket" id="2regular" data-total="100">1x Regular Ticket</option>
</select>


<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options don't have a `rel` attribute. Try using a [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute instead:

```
<option value="1x VIP Ticket" id="one" data-total="160">1x VIP Ticket</option>

...

sum += parseInt($(this).data("total"));
```

EDIT: Based on your last attempt, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("#game1, #game2").find("option:selected").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).data("total"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }

    $("#game1, #game2").change(function() {
        recalculate();
    });

});
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! However, I am fairly new to this, and don't understand how I need to change the rest of the code so it looks for select menus instead of checkboxes..

Comment: `$("#theSelect option:selected").each(...`

Comment: Well, it's grabbing the selected option now which is awesome! But the recalculate function is failing and just giving 'NaN', so it doesn't seem to be pulling the data attribute correctly? I've added the revised code to original question.

Comment: Perfect! Lifesaver. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("rel");
```

Option rel attribute value fetch.

Comment: I do not think `option` tags can have `rel` attributes. Either way this does not add to the current accepted answer, I would consider removing unless you can edit some more information into your answer.

Comment: I think you never use it. So you sent this type of answer. Because yesterday I did it in my project. OK